# SQL Server Agent job not running package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package that I have deployed to the file system.  The owner for the package is my Windows Login. The reason for this is that it needs to write files to another server.  If I make the owner NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT the error that I get is that the files on the remote server cannot be accessed.

The package itself runs under my account.  The package normally takes about 5 minutes to run and works when run directly (double click, click Execute and enter decryption password).  I can tell the package has run because it writes a number of logs to the file system.

I've set up a SQL Server job to run the package.  The job says it's run successfully but there are no logs being written.  I'm not sure where I've gone astray other than there's some account that I'm likely missing.

Has anyone else ever run into this?

Comment: Hint: permissions....

Comment: To summarize: "A package does something fine with my permissions but not another account. Why?" @MitchWheat is likely right in that you have a permission issue but whether it's local file system, remote file system, database, web service, etc we don't know because there's no information in this question. It could also be an expected drive letter doesn't exist. Please edit the existing question providing information about the package and its tasks, the account Agent executes under, whether you use a stored credential for the job subsystem and what logging provider(s) the package uses.

Comment: Which permissions - windows or SQL?  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks guys... I will add this info.

Comment: I've edited the question with regards to which accounts are enabled, etc..

Comment: One additional note... the step that calls the DTSX package is also run under my account.  The package source is the file system.

Comment: Aaargh!  OK - I think I see the issue.  The owner on the job is me, but the "Run As" on the job is the SQL Server Service Account - which doesn't have access to the files on the remote server.  I'm investigating if this can be changed and what the best practice would be.

Comment: Had to add a Proxy Account and this SEEMS to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I needed to set up a proxy Account to run the SQL Server agent.